# Importing spring.ftl using Spring MVC, Sitemesh, Freemarker

Tags: spring-mvc, freemarker, sitemesh

How can I import the spring.ftl macros into a Freemarker template page using Spring MVC, Sitemesh, and Freemarker?

I've configured a Spring MVC app using Sitemesh and Freemarker based on [Ted Young's configuration example](http://tedyoung.me/2011/02/14/spring-sitemesh-and-freemarker/). According to the [Spring MVC/Freemarker](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#view-velocity) integration reference, it is necessary to import the spring.ftl macros in order to bind the backing model to the view via <@spring.bind "command.name"/>. However, doing this:

```
<#import "/spring.ftl" as spring>
<@spring.bind "command.user"/>
```

Results in this exception:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: 
Request processing failed; nested exception is freemarker.
template.TemplateException: Error reading imported file spring.ftl
```

[Others have experienced this issue](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?55855-Error-reading-imported-file-spring-ftl), but I've yet to find a solution in google land. I also attempted to use [this technique](http://tedyoung.me/2011/02/19/freemarker-jsp-taglibs-outside-war/#more-227) (zipping up spring.ftl, placing it in META-INF/lib, and adding the zip to the build path), but it didn't seem to work out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that spring dont know where to look after the `spring.ftl` file:
This is my custom configuration for an MVC project using Boot

```
/**
 * Otras configuraciones de la aplicaciones web, incluyendo algunas definidas en
 * xml. Usar @ImportResource("classpath:/extra-config.xml") en caso de quererse
 * importar configuracion en xml
 */
@Configuration 
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class WebAppConfig
{
    @Autowired
    private ServletContext context;

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeHolderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer(); 
        return placeHolderConfigurer;
    }

   @Bean
    public FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer() throws IOException, TemplateException 
    {
        FreeMarkerConfigurer configurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer()
        {

            @Override
            protected void postProcessConfiguration(freemarker.template.Configuration config) throws IOException, TemplateException
            {
                WebappTemplateLoader WebAppTplLoader = new WebappTemplateLoader(context, "/WEB-INF/ftl");
                ClassTemplateLoader classTplLoader = new ClassTemplateLoader(context.getClassLoader(), "/templates");
                ClassTemplateLoader baseMvcTplLoader = new ClassTemplateLoader(FreeMarkerConfigurer.class, "");
                MultiTemplateLoader mtl = new MultiTemplateLoader(new TemplateLoader[]
                {
                    WebAppTplLoader,
                    classTplLoader,
                    baseMvcTplLoader
                });  
                config.setTemplateLoader(mtl);
            }
        };
        configurer.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8"); 
        configurer.setPreferFileSystemAccess(false); 
        return configurer; 
    }

    @Bean
    public FreeMarkerViewResolver viewResolver()
    {
         FreeMarkerViewResolver viewResolver = new FreeMarkerViewResolver(); 
         viewResolver.setExposeSpringMacroHelpers(true);  
         viewResolver.setExposeRequestAttributes(true);
         viewResolver.setPrefix("");
         viewResolver.setSuffix(".ftl");
         viewResolver.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
         return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

The first 2 loaders allow to load `.ftl` templates in `war` files from "/WEB-INF/ftl" and from regular `jar` files from `src/resources/templates`. 
If you want to use security tags in freemarker the escense are this two lines:

```
         viewResolver.setExposeSpringMacroHelpers(true);  
         viewResolver.setExposeRequestAttributes(true);
```

And the `baseMvcTplLoader` loader to get the `spring.ftl` from `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker`. I advice to explore ftl templates in some [example project](https://github.com/bkielczewski/example-spring-boot-security) or [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-bind-macros) to have a clue of how `spring.ftl` works.

> The configuration of the placeholder is not related to the freemarker
>   configuration, yet its very useful for injecting values in variables
>   from `src/resources/application.properties` by using the `@Value`
>   annotation.

With this you can use all the **spring** power within **freemarker** templates.

Answer (score 0):

I like my spring.ftl included by default without having to add it manually within each view.  In your configuration.

Define your freemarkerConfigurer as such.

```
   @Bean(name = "freemarkerConfig")
public FreeMarkerConfigurer freemarkerConfig() {
    FreeMarkerConfigurer configurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
    configurer.setTemplateLoaderPath("/WEB-INF/views/");
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("xml_escape", new XmlEscape());
    configurer.setFreemarkerVariables(map)
    def settings = new Properties()
    settings['auto_import']  =  'spring.ftl as spring, layout/application.ftl as l'
    configurer.setFreemarkerSettings(settings)
    println "returning freemarker config"
    return configurer;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
<#import "spring.ftl" as spring/>
```

Without `/`

Comment: Really? The [Spring documentation itself](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html) says to use `<#import "/spring.ftl" as spring />`